# Why Openzeppelin ERC721 defines two 'safeTransferFrom'?

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin, erc721

Source code:

```
    /**
     * @dev See {IERC721-safeTransferFrom}.
     */
    function safeTransferFrom(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 tokenId
    ) public virtual override {
        safeTransferFrom(from, to, tokenId, "");
    }

    /**
     * @dev See {IERC721-safeTransferFrom}.
     */
    function safeTransferFrom(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 tokenId,
        bytes memory data
    ) public virtual override {
        require(_isApprovedOrOwner(_msgSender(), tokenId), "ERC721: caller is not token owner or approved");
        _safeTransfer(from, to, tokenId, data);
    }
```

Hi everyone.

While reading the Openzeppelin ERC-721 source code, I found that it defined two `safeTransferFrom` method with different implementations.

I am curious why it's made in this way. Could anyone help me with it?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It follows the [ERC-721](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721) standard that also defines two functions with the same name - but with different input params. Generally in OOP, this is called [function overloading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading).

As you can see in the OpenZeppelin implementation, when you call the function without the `data` param, it passes an empty value.

I can't speak for the authors of the standard, but to me it seems like a more developer friendly approach compared to having to explicitly pass the empty value, since Solidity doesn't allow specifying a default param value.